# Largest possible downsampling factor

Tags: filters

With the intention of converting a single rate LPF FIR filter to multi rate equivalent: what is the largest possible downsampling factor? I found one source that said it was the sampling frequency divided by the frequency at the centre of the transition band, but am seeking verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not one correct answer to this question, other than the theoretical one which would be that the maximum downsampling factor $M$ is given by

$$M=\frac{f_s}{f_c}$$

where $f_c$ is the highest frequency of the (ideally band-limited) signal. Since there's no ideally band-limited signal, it depends on the application how much aliasing can be tolerated. The frequency $f_c$ must be chosen as the frequency above which the signal (after low pass filtering) has no significant energy. What 'significant' means is determined by the application.

Comment: @Chris: this approximates what you read, so consider it sort of verified, in case that wasn't clear. Frequencies below the centre of the transition band will be sort of kept, while frequencies above the centre will be sort of attenuated, and, hence, downsampling such that the lower frequencies are kept makes sense, although, of course, Matt L.'s answer is more strict.